# Subsetting a dataframe to exclude values in the same row as NA

Tags: r, select, subset, na

I have a dataframe called "data". One of the columns is called "reward" and another is called "X.targetResp". I want to create a new dataframe, called "reward", that consists of all values from the column "reward" in "data." HOWEVER, I want to exclude values of the "reward" column that are in the same row as an NA value in the "X.targetResp" column of "data".

I've tried the following:

```
reward <- data$reward %in% filter(!is.na(data$X.targetResp))
reward <- subset(data, reward, !(X.targetResp=="NA"))
reward <- subset(data, reward, !is.na(X.targetResp))
```

...but I get errors for each of them.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, you can use `filter` and `!is.na()` to filter out the ones with NA in `X.targetResp`, and then use the `select` function to select the `reward` column.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create example data frame
dat <- data_frame(reward = 1:5,
                  X.targetResp = c(2, 4, NA, NA, 10))

# Print the data frame
dat
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   reward X.targetResp
#    <int>        <dbl>
# 1      1            2
# 2      2            4
# 3      3           NA
# 4      4           NA
# 5      5           10

# Use the filter function
reward <- dat %>%
  filter(!is.na(X.targetResp)) %>%
  select(reward)
reward
# # A tibble: 3 x 1
# reward
#    <int>
# 1      1
# 2      2
# 3      5
```

And here is a base R solution with the similar logic.

```
subset(dat, !is.na(X.targetResp), "reward")
# A tibble: 3 x 1
reward
#    <int>
# 1      1
# 2      2
# 3      5
```

You can also consider use `drop_na` on `X.targetResp` from the `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
reward <- dat %>%
  drop_na(X.targetResp) %>%
  select(reward)
reward
# # A tibble: 3 x 1
#   reward
#    <int>
# 1      1
# 2      2
# 3      5
```

Here is an example of the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)

reward <- dat[!is.na(X.targetResp), .(reward)]
reward
#    reward
# 1:      1
# 2:      2
# 3:      5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `na.omit`, which is designed to address this problem:

```
# replicating the same example data frame given by @www
data <- data.frame(
  reward = 1:5,
  X.targetResp = c(2, 4, NA, NA, 10)
)

# omitting the rows containing NAs
reward <- na.omit(data)

# resulting data frame with both columns
reward
#   reward X.targetResp
# 1      1            2
# 2      2            4
# 5      5           10

# you can easily extract the first column if necessary
reward[1]
#   reward
# 1      1
# 2      2
# 5      5
```

**Following up @www's comment:**

In case there are other columns you want to dodge:

```
# omitting the rows where only X.targetResp is NA
reward <- data[complete.cases(data["X.targetResp"]),  ]

# resulting data frame with both columns
reward
#   reward X.targetResp
# 1      1            2
# 2      2            4
# 5      5           10

# you can easily extract the first column if necessary
reward[1]
#   reward
# 1      1
# 2      2
# 5      5
```

Comment: The problem with `na.omit` is it may remove more rows than expected because other columns may have `NA`, too.

Comment: @www; Although the question indicates only two columns, I updated my answer to cover the case you mentioned by using `complete.cases`, which is still a simpler solution.

Comment: It is not about which answer is simpler. I just want to remind you it may not be what the OP wants. In addition, there are no evidence that OP's data frame only has two columns. Even there is only two columns, if there are `NA` in the `reward` column, `na.omit` will remove those rows, too.

Comment: Of course! It is always good to have options. Thank you for pointing out the possible edge cases. `complete.cases` now covers these issues. Cheers!